# Variance of a Time Series Fitted to an ARIMA Model

Tags: r, time-series, variance

I think this is a basic question, but maybe I am confusing the concepts.

Suppose I fit an ARIMA model to a time series using, for example, the function auto.arima() in the R forecast package. The model assumes constant variance. How do I obtain that variance? Is it the variance of the residuals?

If I use the model for forecasting, I know that it gives me the conditional mean. I'd like to know the (constant) variance as well.

Thank you.

Bruno

Answer (score 2):

from the arima() help I see

```
sigma2  
  the MLE of the innovations variance.

var.coef    
  the estimated variance matrix of the 
  coefficients coef, which can be extracted 
  by the vcov method.
```

It seems like which you want will depend on your model. I am pretty sure you want sigma2.

to get the sigma2 do:

```
?arima
x=cumsum(rcauchy(1000))

aax=auto.arima(x)
str(aax)
aax$sigma2
```

Comment: Thanks, Seth. I did find that sigma2 field in the documentation, but wasn't sure if that's what I want.

Comment: Ask that question on crossvalidated.com.

Comment: Done: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58407/variance-of-a-time-series-fitted-to-an-arima-model